# How to print/escape underline character in a way that the final word is searchable in a PDF viewer

Tags: pdftex

I have a tex document which includes plain text, tables, tikz state machines, Etc. I have variables, State names an a bunch of other words with underscore in them(e.g. WAIT_FOR_DATA, DATA_RECEIVED). These names cause compiler(pdflatex) errors. Escaping underscore with backslash seems to help, BUT the issue is the final PDF shows the underlines correctly but the final word is not searchable through out the document. it seems like a different but similarly looking character is being used instead of the standard underscore.

is there a way to fix this ?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE
I was asked to provide an example code.

````
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,multirow,graphicx,geometry,hyperref,helvet, float,longtable,multirow,tikz,tikz-timing}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tl}
\geometry{a4paper ,left=0.75in,,right=0.75in,top=1in,bottom=1in,}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{footer}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, shadows, fit}
\usetikztiminglibrary{overlays}                                                             
                                                                                            
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.012in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2in}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}   
something\_something

\end{document}```
````

Comment: it depends on your code what is used, so show a small but complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default OT1 encoding (7-bit) simulates the underscore with a line.
The T1 encoding (8-bit) is a better encoding avoiding some quirks of the OT1 encoding and more support for other glyphs. It can be set by:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If you are using the Computer Modern fonts (7-bit), this switches to the EC fonts.
The newer Latin Modern fonts (kind of successor of the CM/EC fonts)
are even better (more supported glyphs and font formats):

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

With Unicode supporting engines (LuaTeX, XeTeX) add (without package `fontenc`):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

The default are the Latin Modern fonts.

### Summary:

8-bit engines (pdfTeX, vanilla TeX):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Unicode engines (LuaTeX, XeTeX):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

Then the underscore characters should be glyphs that can be copied instead of being simulated in the OT1 encoding by lines (rules).

### PS:

There is also a package `accsupp` for the "ActualText" feature of the PDF format:

```
\usepackage{accsupp}
...
\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={Here_is_a_word}Here\_is\_a\_word\EndAccSupp{}
```

But the syntax is a bit cumbersome and the feature is not well supported by all PDF viewers.

Comment: Wow, never heard of the `accsupp` package. (BTW I'm missing a brace in the example.)

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion worked for me.